# Cytoscape, how to highlight the clicked edge?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to get the clicked edge so to get the highlight the `edge.connectedNodes()`.

The issue that I've found is:
even if I'm able to store the edge id using the

```
 cy.on('tap', function (event) {
    if (event.target.isEdge()) {
        selectedEdgeId = event.target.id;
    }
 }
```

using

```
 cy.edges("#" + vm.selectedEdgeId);
```

I get only data with length equals to 0, i.e. `ca {length: 0, _private{…}}`

Any suggestion on how to get the clicked edge so to get the `connectedNodes()`?

Answer (score 2):

Event.target is the clicked edge itself, so you don't need to save the id or anything. I would suggest this approach:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "100px",
        shape: "rectangle",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".highlight",
      css: {
        "background-color": "red"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "control-point-step-size": 40,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "Top",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "yes",
          faveColor: "#37a32d"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "no",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Third",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Fourth",
          faveColor: "#56a9f7"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "no"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "no",
          target: "Third"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Third",
          target: "Fourth"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Fourth",
          target: "Third"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "dagre"
  }
}));

// bind tapstart to edges and highlight the connected nodes
cy.bind('tapstart', 'edge', function(event) {
  var connected = event.target.connectedNodes();
  connected.addClass('highlight');
});

// bind tapend to edges and remove the highlight from the connected nodes
cy.bind('tapend', 'edge', function(event) {
  var connected = event.target.connectedNodes();
  connected.removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```